# Wait cant find element by linktext

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to navigate through a few steps of a web app.  Have managed to get to the first 2 pages, but the next step fails because it cant find the element, which is a link within a `<li>` item, so Im using FindByLinkText via the Selenium wait helpers

The particular element, which is unique on the page, is a simple anchor like this

```
<ul>
<li>top menu item</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>branch link here</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

The section of my code that fails:

```
$seleniumWait = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait($ChromeDriver, (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 10))
$seleniumWait.Until([OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions]::ElementIsVisible([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::LinkText("branch link here")))
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByLinkText("branch link here").Click()
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "FindElementByLinkText" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I think I may see why however.  If I inspect the page source, there is a lot of jquery being used to construct the menu dynamically.  Just looking at the elements however, I see the link and menu structure as outlined above, but its being dynamically generated as the page loads.  If the elements are seen by the DOM, then the above methods should work, correct?

[update]
I just realized at the point I am trying to do the above, the app has launched a 2nd tab.  Will that throw things off?

Comment: For x = 3, b = c-1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Assuming your only opening a new tab from the parent.

```
#Loop through until we find a new window handle
foreach($window in $ChromeDriver.WindowHandles)
{
    if($currentWindow -ne $window)
    {
        $ChromeDriver.SwitchTo().Window($window);
        break;
    }
}
```